# Failed to load ApplicationContext for JUnit test in Hudson Maven, but no issues locally

Tags: spring, maven, junit, hudson

I've tried just about every configuration I can think of (and reviewed some answers on StackOverflow), but all of our tests show the 'Failed to load ApplicationContext' error when run through Hudson. What is interesting is that some tests appear to run and pass, while some run and fail (as expected), but regardless I'm always getting the errors list for all tests. Here is the basic configuration:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/MyTest-context.xml")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public MyTest() {}

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {
        // Implementation...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

There appears to be a duplicate set of tests running, one for Emma coverage reporting, and the other the normal tests. It is when the tests run for Emma coverage that they are showing the errors. If I turn off the "emma:emma package" goal so those don't run then I don't get the errors, and the tests appear to run fine. I'm not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Hmm.. your problem sounds almost like it doesn't find the application context initially but finds it somehow. I haven't run into this problem although we seem to have pretty similar setup and use Hudson for CI (haven't found time to move to Jenkins yet).

Comment: If you run the tests with "maven test", the tests pass ?

Comment: @gontard Correct, I do not get the errors.

Comment: Did you see the section [2.1 of the Emma FAQ](http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#faq-N10042) ? May be there is an incompatibility between spring and emma clasloader. Could you provide your maven emma plugin configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being close to what gontard was pointing to, which is an issue that was hidden by the way Emma's classloader works. Between my local JUnit tests, what was running in our DEV environment, and what was running in Hudson with Emma, all of them have a different way in which the classloader orders the loading of libraries and classes. I ended up reviewing the stack trace on the test results, and it turns out on my local, a new version of a library was loaded via the POM, but in Hudson Emma was loading an old version of a library first. I had to find and remove the old version, and everything now works fine.